# interface{} to function type conversion

Tags: go

I'm a Go newcomer and I've been battling with this problem almost all day today.

Considering I have these:

```
type HandlerType func()
var object interface{}
var typedObject HandlerType
```

I **can** assign a function to the typedObject variable like this:

```
typedHandler = func() {
    fmt.Println("in a handler!\n")
}
```

But what I need to do is to pass that handler function as an interface{} variable and then convert it somehow to HandlerType which I could call later

I've tried this but it throws an error:

```
typedHandler = object.(HandlerType)
```

results in:

> interface conversion: interface is func(), not main.HandlerType

Basically I need to register functions with different signatures without additional type conversion before registering. So instead of doing this:

```
registerHandler(HandlerTypeString(func() string { ... }))
registerHandler(HandlerTypeVoid(func() { ... }))
```

I want to register handlers like this:

```
registerHandler(func() string { ... })
registerHandler(func() { ... })
```

.. and I don't want to involve reflection at the time of a handler call later

Is it possible?

**Edit**: I've created a playground: http://play.golang.org/p/UlwqkHjt_P

So as I understand there is no way to pass some arbitrary function as **interface{}** and then somehow convert it to HandlerType or some other predefined function type so I would be able to call it without using reflection?

**Edit2**: I've came up with this solution: http://play.golang.org/p/4gUxsgmiPf

There shouldn't be any performance penalties during runtime with this code. But can somebody think out another way of implementing this functionality without **interface{}** ?

Comment: Show full code. `typedHandler = object.(HandlerType)` **will** work if object (of type `interface {}`) really contains an object of `HandlerType`. Show code which is playable on the playground.

Comment: One more: If you are a Go newcommer you should avoid `interface{}`. Finde some other way, writer proper Go code. A newcomer's which for `interface{}` magic smells like code transliteration from some other language.

Comment: I've added a playground where I think I've made clear of what do I want to accomplish :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't, it's a different type, you could just use `object.(func())`, `object.(func() string)`, etc.

```
func main() {
    type HandlerType func()
    var object interface{} = func() {
        fmt.Println("eureka!")
    }
    if f, ok := object.(func()); ok {
        HandlerType(f)()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I've got how to implement what I wanted.
http://play.golang.org/p/4gUxsgmiPf

Comment: Actually for that specific pattern you're probably better off using an interface like @Elwinar suggested.

Answer (score 8):

There is a number of small misconceptions in your question:

1. Type assertion isn't used to cast types. All it do is checking that a variable is of the given type and returning the variable as this underlying type. This operation return a error in your case, which is normal given that `func()` isn't the type `HandlerFunc`.
2. You don't need to do anything to pass a variable as parameter in a function accepting `interface{}`. Every type implicitly implement the empty interface.
3. A `func()` isn't a `HandlerType`, even if `HandlerType` is defined by `type HandlerType func()`. The definition has nothing to do with that.

What you want to do isn't possible. I'm not an expert with reflection, but I don't think that reflection could solve your problem either.

That said, your registering method should define a interface that all registered objects should implement, and use this interface as parameter type. Look at the `database/sql` package [`Register`](https://godoc.org/database/sql#Register) method for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this now with the [reflect.MakeFunc](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#MakeFunc) There is an example there on how to do it